# Add consecutive y values together nvd3/d3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm working with the nvd3 line plus bar chart and would like the line to display the cumulative y values as opposed to the y(height) value in my data set. I'm trying to show the percent change from year to year.

For instance, if there was a 12.2% increase from 2010 - 2011 and a 3.3% increase from 2011-2012, I still want the tooltip to display those numbers, but I want the line to continue increasing rather than dropping back down to 3.3%

Here's what I have so far (this is just example data):

```
var data = [
  {
    "key" : "Quantity" ,
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [ [ 0 , 2300] , [ 1 , 2456] , [ 2 , 2342] ]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price" ,
    "values" : [ [ 0 , 0] , [ 1 , 12.2] , [ 2 , 3.3] ]
  }
].map(function(series) {
  series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
  return series;
});


chart.y1Axis
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',.2f')(d) });

chart.y2Axis
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',.2f')(d) + "%" });
```

EDIT:

Based on the comments, I'm trying to add another item to my array and modify the corresponding .js file.

Here's what I have for the chart:

```
var data = [
  {
    "key" : "Quantity" ,
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [ [ 0 , 2300, 11] , [ 1 , 2456, 14] , [ 2 , 2342, 18] ]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price" ,
    "values" : [ [ 0 , 0, 13] , [ 1 , 12.2, 14] , [ 2 , 3.3, 12] ]
  }
].map(function(series) {
  series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1], z: d[2]} });
  return series;
});
```

And I tried adding both of these lines to the lineplusbarchart.js file:

```
z = function(d) { return d.z}
or
z = function(d) { return d[2]}
```

I can get the tooltip to return "z = function(d) { return d[2]}" but I obviously want the number, not the quoted text.

Comment: NVD3 doesn't do that for you, you will have to modify the source.

Comment: Or more simply, modify your data array by adding a cumulative total variable.